# How to get sum of hours and minutes in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OutTime - InTime, 108), 5) 
FROM Attendance 
WHERE InTime BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '01-31-2016' 
AND Employee=63 
ORDER BY InTime
```

I have got this result.

[[image: table screenshot[1]]

What I want is the sum of all the hours. And how can I write the same query in Linq?

Comment: Side note: Is it your intention to ignore anything that happened *during* the last day of January? If not, it would be far better to have `WHERE InTime >= '20160101' AND InTime < '20160201'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Attendance(OutTime DateTime, InTime DateTime)

-- Sample Data
insert into  #Attendance( InTime, outTime)
values ('2015-12-12 07:30', '2015-12-12 17:30'),
('2015-12-12 07:30', '2015-12-12 17:30'),
('2015-12-13 07:30', '2015-12-13 16:45'),
('2015-12-14 07:30', '2015-12-14 14:34'),
('2015-12-15 07:30', '2015-12-15 18:21')

-- Use DateDiff function to get total minutes between times to achieve greater accuracy then with 'hour'
-- Convert total minutes to hours after adding up total minutes
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime , OutTime)) /60
FROM #Attendance 

DROP TABLE #Attendance
```

Now with more LINQ:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime OutTime { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class AttendanceUser
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UseALambda()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var attendances = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => 
            new Attendance { InTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-rand.Next(x)), OutTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(rand.Next(x)) }).ToList();

        var total = attendances.Sum(x => (x.OutTime - x.InTime).TotalMinutes) / 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know how my this query can be converted to linq query??

Comment: SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime , OutTime)) /60
    FROM Attendance
    WHERE InTime BETWEEN '01-04-2016' AND '01-31-2016' 
    AND Employee=63

Comment: `attendances.Where(x => x.OutTime > a && ....).Sum(x => (x.OutTime - x.InTime).TotalMinutes) / 60;     `

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have a datetype that represents a time *span*. As such, it's usually best to convert everything into `int`s that represent the granularity of the result you need (here, minutes):

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,InTime,OutTime)) as TotalMinutes
FROM Attendance 
WHERE InTime BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160131' 
AND Employee=63 
--ORDER BY InTime
```

And then convert that into (days), hours and minutes in your presentation layer.

Also, as noted below the question, if you want to include events that occurred *within* the last day of January, change your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,InTime,OutTime)) as TotalMinutes
FROM Attendance 
WHERE InTime >= '20160101' AND InTime < '20160201' 
AND Employee=63
```